# Navigate between 2 screen using .then

Tags: react-native, navigation, imagepicker

i m working on a mobile app that takes a picture and then renders it in a different screen, i m able to do so but the thing is when i call the image picker to take the image and then pass it to another screen i get the first screen where i have my button showing for about a second before it navigates to second screen, how can i prevent that , here is ly code :

```js
useEffect(() => { if(image) navigating() }, [image]);

const takePicture=()=>{
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
        mediaType:'photo',
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        includeBase64:true,
        cropping: true,
      }).then(image => {
        setImage(image.path);
      });

}
```

this is the navigating func

```js
const navigating=()=>{
  return navigation.navigate("Result",{
    key: image,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to directly navigate to the second screen after picking an image. What you can do is add a loader to hide the first screen when user is picking an image. Something like this

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

const takePicture=()=>{
    setLoading(true);
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
        mediaType:'photo',
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        includeBase64:true,
        cropping: true,
      }).then(image => {
        navigation.navigate('Result', { key: image });
        setLoading(false);
      });
}

if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator />;

return (....)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use useEffect hook on Image so that when image is set, you can call your navigating function.

*useEffect(() => {
if(image)
navigating()
}, [image]);*

Comment: i tried this but it it still giving me the same result, it is not directly going to the second screen  it still goes back to first screen then quickly to the second

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you cannot use navigation inside the component jsx
you need to use useEffact instead

Comment: i tried to use useffect as the first comment suggested but i still get the same result

Comment: you need to setState in .then() when the state is updated, the useEffact will be called automatically

Comment: yes i m doing that  `const [image, setImage]=useState(null)
useEffect(() => { if(image) navigating() }, [image]);     const takePicture=()=>{
    ImagePicker.openCamera({
        mediaType:'photo',
        width: 300,
        height: 400,
        includeBase64:true,
        cropping: true,
      }).then(image => {
        setImage(image.path);
        
      });}`

Comment: do not use .then(), instead use onChange handler, 
onChange = {() => setImage(image.path)}

Comment: this might sound retarded but I m very new to this I tried to add the handler on my button jsx element but nothing happened and I tried to replace then with it but it is not correct syntactically